# Deciding between obj->func() and func(obj)

Tags: object-oriented, coding-style

I was thinking about this when I was starting to set up some code for a new project: are there any rules of thumb for when a method should be part of an object, and when it should be a stand alone function that takes an object as a parameter?

EDIT: as pointed out in a comment, this can depend on language. I was working in C++ when it came to mind, though I'm this is an issue across a number of languages (and would still love to see answers that pertain to them).

Comment: Depends on a language! In C#/Java/etc. functional programming style is not idiomatic. I Clojure/Lisp object-oriented programming is not idiomatic. I would say this: if you do not need to preserve the state, then go the functional route. If you have to worry about multi-threading, then go the functional route. Other than that, it depends ...

Comment: In Common Lisp, this wouldn't come up.  `(function object ...)` is how these things are written, regardless of what `function` is.

Comment: @Job - I think GSto means func as in imperative procedural programming, as C++ is multi-paradigm, rather than functional programming

Answer (score 9):

- **If it does not conceptionally belong to the class, it should be a standalone function.** (it may also be that it logically belongs to the class, but there are so many similar functions that keeping them all as members would bloat the class interface and compromise encapsulation. In this case it is better to draw a boundary between the "outer circle" of utility functions and the "inner circle" of core class interface functions, the former being standalone functions implemented in terms of the latter.)
- **If it belongs to the class but its first parameter may be an instance of a different type, it should be a standalone (possibly `friend`) function** (a typical example is `operator +`).

  (Scott Meyers puts it more elegantly in [Effective C++ 3rd Edition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321334876), Item 24: *Declare non-member functions when type conversions should apply to all parameters*)
- **if it needs to be virtual or uses private parts of the class, it must be a member.**
- **Otherwise it <strike>should be a member function</strike> is to some extent a matter of preference**.

Note: the code examples you show make me assume the language is C++. In many other languages such as Java the question is meaningless because there are no standalone functions.

Comment: Myers changed his mind: http://www.drdobbs.com/184401197

Comment: @Crazy Eddie, good to know. Thanks and +1 for the link :-)

Answer (score 3):

Prefer non-member, non-friend functions: [*How Non-Member Functions Improve Encapsulation by Scott Meyers*](http://www.drdobbs.com/184401197) :

> When it comes to encapsulation, sometimes less is more.
>
> [...] If you're writing a function that can
>   be implemented as either a member or as a non-friend non-member, you
>   should prefer to implement it as a non-member function. That decision
>   increases class encapsulation. When you think encapsulation, you
>   should think non-member functions. [...]

Answer (score 0):

The [single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) often helps, when you have to decide whether some method or more broader some functionality belongs to an object.

Please also note, that if some functionality related to some object doesn't belong to one object, it still might make sense to encapsulate it in another object, as in `other->func(obj)`.

```
class Mouth {
    void say(String msg);
    void sayHello(Person to);
    void sayBye(Person to);
}
```

Now the 2nd and 3rd method will actually just call the say method and they really don't belong to the responsibility of the `Mouth` anyway.

```
interface Out {
    void say(String msg);
}
class Mouth implements Out {
    void say(String msg);
}
class Phrases {
    void new(Language language);
    void sayHello(Person to, Out over);
    void sayBye(Person to, Out over);
}
```

Of course it might make more sense to pass an `Out`-instance to `Phrases` upon construction. Or to wrap it in yet another class. Or whatever.
But it definitely doesn't make sense to have those methods in `Mouth`, as the SRP suggests.